# How I will get datepicker like this

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to implement a datepicker like the one available over here: [Datepicker Demo](https://mobile.goindigo.in/Consumer/flightBooking)

Can anyone let me know which date picker is this and from where I will get the same like that.?

Comment: Thats jquery-ui datepicker, and you've tagged it!

Comment: Yes, but I didn't see anything like that on `jquery-ui` demo page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Documentation**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

[**Simple DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4bKF/)

```
$('input').datepicker();
```

Comment: Yes..but is not the same as available over there.

Comment: What do you mean, the theme or the jQuery dialog with the datepicker?

Comment: @VishalSuthar it is the same - they just have it wrapped in a jQuery UI Dialog

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ So that what I want to implement..can you please let me know how can I do that.?

Comment: @VishalSuthar this is not serious, you should take some initiative on your side...

Comment: @VishalSuthar here is documentation on jquery dialog aswell http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the jQuery UI datepicker or the HTML5 datepicker. Check the fiddle for a DEMO

```
<input type="date" />
```

Or ..

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/magnusburton/HcEeb/)